# Combine SerializerMethodField and DateField in django rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am new in django and rest framework. I got this Event serializer and in it I want to return localized dates. But when updating event I want to use date validation. So basically I want to combine SerializerMethodField when fetching and DateField validation when saving/updating.Thanks

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from account.models import Events

import main.helpers as helpers

class EventsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=200)
    url = serializers.CharField(required=False, max_length=100)
    allDay = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    # start = serializers.DateField(format=None, input_formats=None)
    # end = serializers.DateField(format=None, input_formats=None)
    start = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_start_local')
    end = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_end_local')
    def get_start_local(self, obj):
        return helpers.utcToLocal(obj.start)
    def get_end_local(self, obj):
        return helpers.utcToLocal(obj.end)
    class Meta:
        model = Events
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'url', 'allDay', 'published', 'start', 'end')
        # fields = ('id', 'title', 'url', 'allDay', 'published', 'start', 'start_local', 'end', 'end_local')
```

Answer (score 0):

For displaying a formatted date, you can use the following structure:

`start = serializers.DateField(format='%m-%d-%Y', input_formats=['%m-%d-%Y'], source='created')`

I don't think you can handle the serializer field and serializer methodfield in this way. If you're not able to achieve what you want with `input_formats` I think you could override your POST method in the view, and update the data that you pass to your serializer in there.